# Smartdiagram - Change Position in twocolumn Layout

Tags: positioning, smartdiagram

I am new to StackExchange and I am a beginner with LaTeX, so bare with me :)

Anyways, I have a problem regarding the placement of a smartdiagram Diagram in my document.

[image]

The sequence digram reaches into the text in the second column. How can I fix this? I have already tried to put the diagram in a center environment and to create a minipage for the diagram, but it didn't work.

And also, if you have suggests for further improvement of my document sytle, let me know it down below :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\linespread{0.95}
package{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Test, Test, Test}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Smartdiagram tries to be smart, but acts as you define it. Hence it will not resize its content and with the current content your sequence diagram is too wide. One option would be to reduce the fontsize.

Comment: please try to remove all errors in your document example! also make it shorter and use dummy text for its context and preserve only images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm,
          columnsep=1cm}        % <---
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}                  % <---
\smartdiagramset{
sequence item text width=16mm,  % <---
sequence item font size=\small  % <---
                }
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]%
{Test, Test, Test}
\end{center}                   % <---

\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

changes in comparison to your mwe are indicated by `% <---`

Comment: Huge thank you for the solution and also for some further improvements :)